# Rails I18n not replacing variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, i18n-gem

I'm having trouble with some of my translations not having their variable replacements replaced with the text I supply and instead just outputting the translation literally.

An example translation

```
formats:
   view_all_other: "View all other %{format_title}"
```

An example use (HAML)

```
= link_to t('formats.view_all_other', format_title: @format.title.downcase), "/#{@format.to_param}/all"
```

What gets output

[image]

I've been scouring the web, but I haven't seen anyone with this issue. This is the first time I've used i18n but it doesn't look like I've got anything set up wrong, other translations work correctly (including ones with variable replacements).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*facepalm* I'd had issues with another translation and I initially called the variable 'format', I suspected it might be a reserved word or something of the sort so I changed all the translations to use format_title and forgot to update the views.

Answer (score 0):

Your translation should be in hierarchy of language. Lets see en.yml, then translation should be like this:

```
en:
  formats:
   view_all_other: "View all other %{format_title}"
```

Comment: It is like that, I just omitted the en: for brevity. Other translations (including ones with variables work) but this one doesn't.

Comment: Can you try, some other variable under same formats hierarchy and check if it works?

Comment: There is another translation under formats with a variable that works correctly.